# CSS nth-of-type on same DOM level

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wasn't able to get nth-of-type(2n+1) selector to select odd and even rows in the following example. 
What I'd like the nth-of-type selector to do is to provide a different style for the odd rows having class "row-data row-header" and a different style for the odd rows having class "row-data row-content". 
I resorted to using jQuery on document load to accomplish this by manually adding an "odd" class to the rows selectively. Is there a better (CSS-only) way of doing this?

```js
function toggleRowContent(cnt) {
  $(cnt).parents(".row-header").first().next(".row-cnt").slideToggle("fast");
  $(".toggleIcon", $(cnt)).toggleClass("fa-chevron-right");
  $(".toggleIcon", $(cnt)).toggleClass("fa-chevron-down");
}

function alternateRowBackgroundColours() {
  $(".row-header").each(function(i, e) {
    if (i % 2 != 0)
      $(this).addClass("odd");

    $(".row-content", $(this).next(".row-cnt")).each(function(j, e) {
      if (j % 2 != 0)
        $(this).addClass("odd");
    });
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  alternateRowBackgroundColours();
});
```

```css
.row-data {
  border-bottom: solid 1px #ccc;
}
.row-cnt {
  border: solid 1px #5A82B3;
}
.row-content {
  margin: 0 15px;
}
.row-content .col {
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
.row-header .col {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.row-header .btnToggleContent {
  width: 35px;
  height: 30px;
}
.row-data.row-header(2n+1) .col {
  background-color: #e7e7e7;
}
.row-data.row-content(2n+1) .col {
  background-color: #c8ebed;
}
.row-data.row-header.odd .col {
  background-color: #e7e7e7;
}
.row-data.row-content.odd .col {
  background-color: #c8ebed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/fontawesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row row-data row-header">
    <div class="col col-sm-12 col-md-12">
      <!-- HEADER CONTENT ... -->
      My header 1
      <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btnToggleContent" onclick="toggleRowContent(this)"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right toggleIcon"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row row-cnt container" style="display: none">
    <div class="row row-data row-content">
      <div class="col col-sm-12 col-md-12">
        <!-- ROW CONTENT -->My content 1.1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row row-data row-content">
      <div class="col col-sm-12 col-md-12">
        <!-- ROW CONTENT -->My content 1.2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row row-data row-content">
      <div class="col col-sm-12 col-md-12">
        <!-- ROW CONTENT -->My content 1.3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row row-data row-header">
    <div class="col col-sm-12 col-md-12">
      <!-- HEADER CONTENT ... -->
      My header 2
      <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btnToggleContent" onclick="toggleRowContent(this)"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right toggleIcon"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row row-cnt container" style="display: none">
    <div class="row row-data row-content">
      <div class="col col-sm-12 col-md-12">
        <!-- ROW CONTENT -->My content 2.1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row row-data row-content">
      <div class="col col-sm-12 col-md-12">
        <!-- ROW CONTENT -->My content 2.2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT:** Adding some more detail to my attempt. Check the full working snippet above.

This is my desired CSS:

```
.row-data.row-header(2n+1) .col { background-color: #e7e7e7; }
.row-data.row-content(2n+1) .col { background-color: #c8ebed; }
```

But it doesn't work. Using "odd" instead of 2n+1 doesn't make any difference. 
So what I did was this:

```
<script>
    function alternateRowBackgroundColours()
    {
        $(".row-header").each(function (i, e)
        {
            if (i % 2 != 0)
                $(this).addClass("odd");

            $(".row-content", $(this).next(".row-cnt")).each(function (j, e)
            {
                if (i % 2 != 0)
                    $(this).addClass("odd");
            });
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        alternateRowBackgroundColours();
    });
</script>
```

And then I added this CSS:

```
.row-data.row-header.odd .col { background-color: #e7e7e7; }
.row-data.row-content.odd .col { background-color: #c8ebed; }
```

The number of row-header(s) and the corresponding row-content(s) is dynamic and there is a toggle button on each row-header which shows the corresponding row-content(s) like an accordion.

This is the result

[image: snapshot of the result]

Comment: Show us your current attempt.

Comment: I added some more details

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since all rows are siblings the use of `odd` ore `even` will take in count both headers and contents so you really need for your headers a selector to skip the content rows like this:

```
.row-header:nth-child(4n+1) {
  background:red;
}
```

And for the intern content just use:

```
.row-cnt > div:nth-child(odd){
  background:#999;
}
```

---

### Check this snippet:

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.row-cnt > div{
  background: #f1f1f1;
  padding:3px;
}
.row-cnt > div:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #999;
}
.row-header {
  color: white;
  background: blue;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  padding: 10px;
}
.row-header:nth-child(4n+1) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="row row-data row-header">
  <div class="col col-sm-12 col-md-12">
    <!-- HEADER CONTENT ... -->
    My header 1
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btnToggleContent" onclick="toggleRowContent(this)"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right toggleIcon"></i></a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row row-cnt">
  <div class="row row-data row-content">
    <div class="col col-sm-12 col-md-12">
      <!-- ROW CONTENT -->My content 1.1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row row-data row-content">
    <div class="col col-sm-12 col-md-12">
      <!-- ROW CONTENT -->My content 1.2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row row-data row-content">
    <div class="col col-sm-12 col-md-12">
      <!-- ROW CONTENT -->My content 1.3</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row row-data row-header">
  <div class="col col-sm-12 col-md-12">
    <!-- HEADER CONTENT ... -->
    My header 2
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btnToggleContent" onclick="toggleRowContent(this)"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right toggleIcon"></i></a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row row-cnt">
  <div class="row row-data row-content">
    <div class="col col-sm-12 col-md-12">
      <!-- ROW CONTENT -->My content 2.1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row row-data row-content">
    <div class="col col-sm-12 col-md-12">
      <!-- ROW CONTENT -->My content 2.2</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row row-data row-header">
  <div class="col col-sm-12 col-md-12">
    <!-- HEADER CONTENT ... -->
    My header 3
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btnToggleContent" onclick="toggleRowContent(this)"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right toggleIcon"></i></a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row row-cnt">
  <div class="row row-data row-content">
    <div class="col col-sm-12 col-md-12">
      <!-- ROW CONTENT -->My content 3.1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row row-data row-content">
    <div class="col col-sm-12 col-md-12">
      <!-- ROW CONTENT -->My content 3.2</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row row-data row-header">
  <div class="col col-sm-12 col-md-12">
    <!-- HEADER CONTENT ... -->
    My header 4
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btnToggleContent" onclick="toggleRowContent(this)"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right toggleIcon"></i></a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row row-cnt">
  <div class="row row-data row-content">
    <div class="col col-sm-12 col-md-12">
      <!-- ROW CONTENT -->My content 4.1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row row-data row-content">
    <div class="col col-sm-12 col-md-12">
      <!-- ROW CONTENT -->My content 4.2</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row row-data row-header">
  <div class="col col-sm-12 col-md-12">
    <!-- HEADER CONTENT ... -->
    My header 5
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btnToggleContent" onclick="toggleRowContent(this)"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right toggleIcon"></i></a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row row-cnt">
  <div class="row row-data row-content">
    <div class="col col-sm-12 col-md-12">
      <!-- ROW CONTENT -->My content 2.1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row row-data row-content">
    <div class="col col-sm-12 col-md-12">
      <!-- ROW CONTENT -->My content 2.2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the number of row-header and row-content is dynamic. I can't use 4n+1.

Comment: Sorry, I got it wrong. Your solution works!! Thank you

Comment: np mate glad to help U @erionpc you don't need to post your own answer if this one solves your issue mark it as solved

Answer (score 1):

Use `nth-child` instead of `nth-of-type` to target odd numbers locally.

```css
.row.row-data.row-header:nth-child(odd) {
    /* your styles here */
}
```

```css
.row.row-data.row-header:nth-child(odd) {
  background: red;
}
.row.row-data.row-content:nth-child(odd) {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="row row-data row-header">
  <div class="col col-sm-12 col-md-12">
    <!-- HEADER CONTENT ... -->
    My header 1
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btnToggleContent" onclick="toggleRowContent(this)"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right toggleIcon">icon</i></a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row row-cnt" style="">
  <div class="row row-data row-content">
    <div class="col col-sm-12 col-md-12">
      <!-- ROW CONTENT -->My content 1.1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row row-data row-content">
    <div class="col col-sm-12 col-md-12">
      <!-- ROW CONTENT -->My content 1.2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row row-data row-content">
    <div class="col col-sm-12 col-md-12">
      <!-- ROW CONTENT -->My content 1.3</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row row-data row-header">
  <div class="col col-sm-12 col-md-12">
    <!-- HEADER CONTENT ... -->
    My header 2
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btnToggleContent" onclick="toggleRowContent(this)"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right toggleIcon">icon</i></a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row row-cnt" style="">
  <div class="row row-data row-content">
    <div class="col col-sm-12 col-md-12">
      <!-- ROW CONTENT -->My content 2.1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row row-data row-content">
    <div class="col col-sm-12 col-md-12">
      <!-- ROW CONTENT -->My content 2.2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't believe `My header 2` is supposed to be red. `nth-of-child` selects on element sibling element order and not classes. `My header 2` has an outer `<div>` that is the third element of all the top level elements and thus highlights it.

Answer (score 0):

check this code snippet

```css
div.row-data.row-header:nth-of-type(2n+1){
  display:block;
  background:red;
}

div.row-data.row-content:nth-of-type(2n+1){
  display:block;
  background:green;
}
```

```html
<div class="row row-data row-header">
    <div class="col col-sm-12 col-md-12">
        <!-- HEADER CONTENT ... -->
        My header 1
        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btnToggleContent" onclick="toggleRowContent(this)"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right toggleIcon">hello</i></a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row row-cnt">
    <div class="row row-data row-content">
        <div class="col col-sm-12 col-md-12"><!-- ROW CONTENT -->My content 1.1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row row-data row-content">
        <div class="col col-sm-12 col-md-12"><!-- ROW CONTENT -->My content 1.2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row row-data row-content">
        <div class="col col-sm-12 col-md-12"><!-- ROW CONTENT -->My content 1.3</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row row-data row-header">
    <div class="col col-sm-12 col-md-12">
        <!-- HEADER CONTENT ... -->
        My header 2
        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btnToggleContent" onclick="toggleRowContent(this)"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right toggleIcon"></i></a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row row-cnt" style="display: none">
    <div class="row row-data row-content">
        <div class="col col-sm-12 col-md-12"><!-- ROW CONTENT -->My content 2.1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row row-data row-content">
        <div class="col col-sm-12 col-md-12"><!-- ROW CONTENT -->My content 2.2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I don't believe `My header 2` is supposed to be red. `nth-of-type` selects on element type and not classes. `My header 2` has an outer `<div>` that is the third element of all the top level elements and thus highlights it.

Comment: i didnt get you completely .Is this what you are expecting?

Comment: I just added more details to my situation. This doesn't work unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

It may be more worthwhile to use the `odd` keyword.

```
.row-data.row-content:nth-of-type(odd) {

}
```

Comment: No, already tried. It doesn't work. Thank you. I added more details to my situation.